# Unable to parse xml attributes through jQuery .

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

On select of a accordian , i am capturing the click evet and trying to read the xml file and parse it .

I have the following xml file which I defined in javascript itself.

```
<categories>

  <category id="2" name="Pepsi" >
     <products>
      <product id="858" name="7UP" price="24.4900" />
      <product id="860" name="Aquafina" price="24.4900" />
      </products>
  </category>

  <category id="4" name="Coke" >
     <products>
      <product id="811" name="ThumpsUp" price="24.4900" />
      <product id="813" name="Maaza" price="24.4900" />
    </products>
  </category>

 </categories>
```

But I am unable to parse the xml file.

So that once I get the elements from xml parsing I can add it to the h4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Basic jQuery Accordion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
var xmldocu = '<categories><category id="2" name="Pepsi" ><products><product id="858" name="7UP" price="24.4900" /><product id="860" name="Aquafina" price="24.4900" /></products></category><category id="4" name="Coke" ><products><product id="811" name="ThumpsUp" price="24.4900" /><product id="813" name="Maaza" price="24.4900" /></products></category></categories>' ;

          $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3",          
                    autoheight: false,
                    active: false,
                    alwaysOpen: false,
                    fillspace: false,
                    collapsible: true,

                    //heightStyle: content   //auto, fill, content
                });

$("#accordion").accordion({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
     var selectedeleemnt = ui.newHeader.text();
           if(selectedeleemnt=="Javascript")
           {
           $(xmldocu).find("categories").each(function () {
           var tsq = $(this).find("category").attr('name').text();
           alert(tsq);
           });
           }
    }
});


            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div style="width: 468px;">
        <div id="accordion">

            <h3><a href="#">Javascript</a></h3>
            <div>
                <h4>Testt</h4>
             </div>

            <h3><a href="#">Other</a></h3>
            <div>
                <h4>Stuff</h4>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `find("categories")` does not work because `categories` is the root node. You're already on it, and `find` looks for descendent nodes.

Your next problem is that `attr` returns a string, so you don't need to call `text` on it.

The following code does what you expect:

```
$(xmldocu).find("category").each(function () {
    var tsq = $(this).attr('name');//.text();
    alert(tsq);
});
```